# adding a constant value to the results of an progress query

Tags: sql, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

Is there anyway to add a constant value in the results of a progress query?

In sql server you can do it by going

```
select *, 1 As DateID from dbo.customers
```

1 being the static field inserted
Not sure how or if you can do this in a progress db?

Comment: How are you going to use the query result?

Are you populating a temp-table, a ProDataset? Visualizing this in a GUI Browse widget? Are you processing the query in code?

Comment: Can you please post the sample output for this query?

Comment: Im moving data to a tables using an SSIS package. I have an ODBC source and an OLE DB destination. I want one value to always be true in my destination table. I know there are other ways to do this. I was just curious to learn if Progress allows you to define constant values in query results.

Comment: Sample results would simply be all the data in the table plus another column titled "DateID" with all values of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to add constant values to the result when you use "*" in the query. One workaround is to write all the column names instead of using "*" and then at last use constant value in the query.

Example:

```
select c1, c2, c3, c4, 1 as DateID from dbo.customers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     SELECT * 
       FROM (SELECT 'somestaticvalue' AS staticvalcolumn
               FROM "PUB"."_Db" AS dummy 
             OFFSET 0 ROWS 
              FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) AS staticvalplaceholder
 RIGHT JOIN "PUB"."Customer" cust on 1=1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.